# Realm default value property crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

When I create an object from restkit with a null property, the app crashes saying:

> No value or default value specified for property 'secondHeader' in
>   'FZPublication'

but the method defaultPropertyValues has a default value for the property

```
+(NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
    return @{
             @"serviceId" : @0,
             @"filterId" : @0,
             @"proccessDate" : @"",
             @"relation" : @"",
             @"header" : @"",
             @"text" : @"",
             @"remoteId" : @0,
             @"versionId" : @0,
             @"footer" : @"",
             @"secondHeader" : @"",
             @"companyRemoteId" : @0,
             };
}
```

My restkit mapping is:

```
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[FZPublication class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"IdServico":@"serviceId",
                                                  @"IdFiltro":@"filterId",
                                                  @"Lido":@"read",
                                                  @"DtProcessamento":@"proccessDate",
                                                  @"Relacao":@"relation",
                                                  @"Cabecalho1":@"header",
                                                  @"Cabecalho2":@"secondHeader",
                                                  @"Texto":@"text",
                                                  @"Id":@"remoteId",
                                                  @"IdEmpresa":@"companyRemoteId",
                                                  @"IdVersao":@"versionId",
                                                  @"DtPublicacao":@"publicationDateString",
                                                  @"NomeDiario" : @"diaryName",
                                                  @"DtDisponibilizacao" : @"availableDateString",
                                                  @"NDiario" : @"diaryNumber",
                                                  @"NProcesso" : @"proccessNumber",
                                                  @"NPagina" : @"pageNumber",
                                                  @"Rodape" : @"footer"
                                                  }];
```

anybody has an idea what is happing?

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint so it stops when it crashes. Post that code so we can see what it's doing

Comment: Can you please share your RestKit mapping code as well?

Comment: @Chris the exception breakpoint stops in a realm code, I am just saving in the restkit callback

Comment: RestKit currently does not know how to take RLMObject's default values into account when mapping. You'll have to make sure that no nil/null values get mapped manually.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating and storing that object in Realm? Keep in mind that you can't save any property with null value in Realm, because it will always crash.